# Compile time error in using variadic parameters with passing function as parameter into another function

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

I am a newbie in Swift and I got a compile time error in Playground (highlighted at the "return f(values)" statement):

error: MyPlayground.playground:6:14: error: cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'
    return f(values)

The code is as follows:

```
func max (_ values : Int...) -> Int {
    var maxVal : Int = values[0]
    for i in values {
        if (i > maxVal) {
            maxVal = i
        }
    }
    return maxVal
}

func fun (by f:(Int...) -> Int, values:Int... ) -> Int {
    return f(values)
}


print(fun(by:max, values:1,2,3,4,5))
```

What is the error in the code? Thanks for advance.

---

Edit:
The answer "How to forward functions with variadic parameters?" suggested calling another function with array parameter, which I don't really want because there will be extra function call overhead.

My problem is: The code looks syntactically correct, please helps to point out the possible error(s) so I can correct it if encountered in other place.  Thanks.

Actually if I replace all "Int..." with "[Int]", everything work fine but the caller statement will be a bit ugly...

---

Edit 2:
As of Swift 4.1 (in Xcode 9.2), the function that forward variadic parameter(s) will IMPLICITLY change it to a single parameter of array of individual parameter(s).  To workaround:

```
func max (_ values : [Int]) -> Int {
    var maxVal : Int = values[0]
    for i in values {
        if (i > maxVal) {
            maxVal = i
        }
    }
    return maxVal
}

func fun (by f:([Int]) -> Int, values:Int... ) -> Int {
    return f(values)
}

print(fun(by:max, values:1,2,3,4,5))
```

Don't know whether this is a bug of the compiler or not :)

Comment: Here Values is type Of Array thats Why . values Is Type Of Int Array

Comment: Please see Edit, thanks.

Comment: Just found a workaround without function overloading and want to share , see Edit 2